# Can´t reach localhost´s API by Postman

Tags: postman, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

When I try to make a postman call to an API instance running localhost using the VPN, I immediately get a 500 error to the postman. On the other hand, when I don’t use VPN, I manage to connect to the API locally, but it can’t connect to the DB because I’m not using VPN. I'm desperate, I can't work. Please, could you help me?

I received this API´s error from VS2022:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is SSL verification turned off in Postman?  For local development work, I know I usually have to have this disabled: https://i.stack.imgur.com/liL11.png

Comment: @TimothyG. Yes, it turned off. But it is still not working.